# Hiding a column blocked all tables in report server?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportserver

I want to hide a column of a table in my report (*.rdl file) based on a incoming parameter. I have defined my column visibility and tablix visibility of that column like this;

> =IIF(Parameters!CompanyId.Value = "53",False,True)

But this hides whole table. None of the column or heading not loading.
If I change the condition like ;

> =IIF(Parameters!CompanyId.Value = "53",true,false) it works for all companies(means table laoding for all companies. Not any change for column)

What is wrong in my expression?

[image]

[image]

Comment: It may help with an example image of what is happening and what you expect to happen.

Comment: @aduguid I have added 2 screenshots. first shows my table with few columns. For on column as i said I try to hide that column based on a condition.Do you know what Im doing wrong here?

Comment: Sorry, but where exactly did you click to set the visibility?  You need to right-click the column header specifically and go to column visibility, not tablix visibility settings.  Additionally, you can simplify the expression by just using `=Parameters!CompanyId.Value = "53"`. This will set the `Hidden` property to true when the CompanyId is equal to 53 and the column will show otherwise.

Comment: @Steve-o169 Thanks for suggestion. I made as you said.Now table is laoding but not the column at all(removed tablix visibility option) How can I define not equal property (it is <> or !=)? =Parameters!CompanyId.Value <> "53". I want to show that column, if companyid=53 only not for other comapny Ids

Comment: @Steve-o169, For me it is showing the column for all companies or not showing. I tried few combinations. But none is success. eg: =IIF(Parameters!CompanyId.Value = "53",true,false)

Comment: @Steve-o169 SOrry my bad, it is wokring.Thanks for hint

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
 Go to Column Groups and click on the down arrow to the right, opening Advanced Mode.
 You should see a row (Static) just above your (Details) row.
 Select it and you should see the row in you Tablix is selected.
 Go the the Properties for this and place you code in the Hidden Field Expression.